# URL Rewrite and Masked Redirection

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, rewrite, redirection

I have a site that is actually a tumblr account for a client. I need to set it to that: blog.foo.net actually redirects to blah.tumblr.com, while still using blog.foo.net. This would be simple using GoDaddy's control panel, but this isn't possible with the control panel in use by the client, which only allows me to create a blog.foo.net and point it to one of my own webservers. My workplace only has Windows 2008 R2 servers.

I keep finding information on URL Rewrite, but how do I get URL Rewrite to do what I need here? I just need to forward the blog.foo.net to blah.tumblr.com without losing the URL.

Comment: How did you go with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be following the 'custom domain name' instructions from tumblr.

Essentially what you're doing is **updating DNS records for your domain**.

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains

> How do I set up a custom domain for my blog?
>
> Buy a domain from a registrar Make a configuration change (A-record
>   and/or CNAME). These are instructions to update DNS records for your
>   domain with your registrar (GoDaddy).
>
> Do I need to change the nameservers for my domain? Nope
>
> How do I know if I set up my domain properly? Wait upto 72hrs then
>   check.
>
> What happens when someone visits my Tumblr URL? They will
>   automatically be redirected to your new custom domain (i.e.
>   david.tumblr.com --> davidslog.com).